# How can I fix this error: "BiopythonWarning: Partial codon, len(sequence) not a multiple of three."?

Tags: python, biopython

For an assignment, I need to write a code that translates an rna sequence ffrom a fasta file to an amino acid sequence. However, I keep getting the following warning message:
" BiopythonWarning: Partial codon, len(sequence) not a multiple of three. Explicitly trim the sequence or add trailing N before translation. This may become an error in future."

I tried to add trailing N, but it still doesn't seem to work. I think there is probably a mistake in my code, but I'm not sure where.

This is my code:

```
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio import SeqIO
seq_records = SeqIO.parse('rna.fasta', 'fasta')
amino_acids1 = []
amino_acids2 = []
amino_acids3 = []

for record in seq_records:

# starting from nucleotide 1
if len(record) %3 ==0:
     amino_acids1.append(record.translate())
elif (len(record)+1) %3 ==0:
    recordN = record + Seq('N')
    amino_acids1.append(recordN.translate())
elif (len(record)+2) %3 ==0:   
    recordNN = record + Seq('N') + Seq('N')
    amino_acids1.append(recordNN.translate())
print("FIRST")
print(amino_acids1)
with open('rna_out.fasta', 'w') as p_file: 
    SeqIO.write(amino_acids1, p_file, 'fasta')


# starting from nucleotide 2
record2 = record[1:]
if len(record2) %3 ==0:
     amino_acids2.append(record2.translate())
elif (len(record2)+1) %3 ==0:
    record2N = record + Seq('N')
    amino_acids2.append(record2N.translate())
elif (len(record2)+2) %3 ==0:   
    record2NN = record + Seq('N') + Seq('N')
    amino_acids2.append(record2NN.translate() )
print("SECOND")
print(amino_acids2)
with open('rna_out.fasta', 'w') as p_file: 
    SeqIO.write(amino_acids2, p_file, 'fasta')


# starting from nucleotide 3
record3 = record[2:]
if len(record3) %3 ==0:
    amino_acids3.append(record3.translate())
elif (len(record3)+1) %3 ==0:
    record3N = record + Seq('N')
    amino_acids3.append(record3N.translate())
elif (len(record3)+2) %3 ==0:
    record3NN = record + Seq('N') + Seq('N')
    amino_acids3.append(record3NN.translate())
print("THIRD")
print(amino_acids3)
with open('rna_out.fasta', 'w') as p_file: 
    SeqIO.write(amino_acids3, p_file, 'fasta')
```

Normally, this would give 3 possible translations for each of the sequences from the fasta file. However, the output doesn't seem to be correct.

These are the first 3 lines, which should be 3 different translations of the first sequence in the fasta file:

FIRST
[SeqRecord(seq=Seq('GAKRTDRT*S*VINKLSLLYTSCETIDCYIFFL', HasStopCodon(ExtendedIUPACProtein(), '*')), id='', name='', description='', dbxrefs=[])]
SECOND
[SeqRecord(seq=Seq('GAKRTDRT*S*VINKLSLLYTSCETIDCYIFFL', HasStopCodon(ExtendedIUPACProtein(), '*')), id='', name='', description='', dbxrefs=[])]
THIRD
[SeqRecord(seq=Seq('CQKN*SDVVVGH*QTVVALHVMRND*LLYLFP', HasStopCodon(ExtendedIUPACProtein(), '*')), id='', name='', description='', dbxrefs=[])]

I don't know where it went wrong, but this is definitely not a correct translation. If you know where I made a mistake, I would really appreciate your help!!

Comment: There are 6 possible translations not 3, checkout my script on this https://github.com/chris-rands/CR_bioinformatics_utilities/blob/master/scripts/faTranslateBioPython.py ; the `pad_seq` function will prevent the warning

Comment: @Chris_Rands, I don't like your `pad_seq` logic `{0: seq, 1: seq+'NN', 2: seq+'N'}[len(seq) % 3]` as it creates two new, potentially lengthy, strings on every call and then tosses one or both of them.  I've done a rework of `pad_seq` in my answer which you should be able to modify for your purposes.

Comment: @cdlane Agreed, looking again, maybe better, `seq + ['', 'NN', 'N'][len(seq) % 3]`

Comment: @Chris_Rands, yes.  The indexed list idiom really only works if there is no cost to the items in the list and this is the case with your revision.  The tricky issue here is the first item (empty string) as you risk creating a copy of `seq` when `seq` itself will do.  But checking with `id()`, it looks to me that it doesn't create a new string.  Do test for yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach might have worked but you have a copy & paste error in your code:

```
record2 = record[1:]
if len(record2) %3 ==0:
     amino_acids2.append(record2.translate())
elif (len(record2)+1) %3 ==0:
    record2N = record + Seq('N')
```

Note that `record` on the last line should be `record2`.  You make this error at least four times.  I believe that the code @Chris_Rands directs you to has valuable insight into the problem, e.g. translating the reverse complements as well, but I would not recommend the `pad_seq()` function in that code.

Below's a rework of `pad_seq()` integrated into your code:

```
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio import SeqIO

def pad_seq(sequence):
    """ Pad sequence to multiple of 3 with N """

    remainder = len(sequence) % 3

    return sequence if remainder == 0 else sequence + Seq('N' * (3 - remainder))

seq_records = SeqIO.parse('rna.fasta', 'fasta')

amino_acids1 = []
amino_acids2 = []
amino_acids3 = []

for record in seq_records:

    # starting from nucleotide 1
    amino_acids1.append(pad_seq(record).translate())
    print("FIRST")
    print(amino_acids1)
    # ...

    # starting from nucleotide 2
    record2 = record[1:]
    amino_acids2.append(pad_seq(record2).translate())
    print("SECOND")
    print(amino_acids2)
    # ...

    # starting from nucleotide 3
    record3 = record[2:]
    amino_acids3.append(pad_seq(record3).translate())
    print("THIRD")
    print(amino_acids3)
    # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to silence the warning (and all other Biopython warnings!) if you simply want to ignore the warning. In my situation the warning was unnecessary and it polluted my logs, but I also did not want to edit the sequences.
The following code comes directly from the biopython annotation of the BiopythonWarning class, so it is kind of the official way to mute the warning:

```
import warnings
from Bio import BiopythonWarning
warnings.simplefilter('ignore', BiopythonWarning)
```